# Distribution of Moving Average of Bernoulli distributed Variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, stochastic-processes, moving-average

Given a series of n i.i.d. Bernoulli experiments with probability p for success each, I'd like to know the probability of crossing a threshold of somewhere having k successes over m consecutive experiments.

For specific p, m and n I could try a Monte Carlo simulation, but I'd rather know a distribution for the moving average or at least a good approximation. The upper bound of the probability of crossing the threshold by first calculating the probability "prob1" of k or more successes in m experiments, and then calculating the probability of at least 1 occurrence in (n-m+1) tries with probability prob1 is too high.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this sounds like a binomial distribution. I'm a little confused about n iid bernoulli experiments (a binomial) but m experiments.

Comment: @AdamPollack I think it means that if say $n=20$ and $p=\frac12$ you might get a sequence like $1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1$.  If you have $m=5$ then you can get five consecutive terms which add up to $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$, while $0$ and $5$ are also theoretically possible but did not happen in this example, so the  threshold at $k=4$ is reached but the threshold at $k=5$ is not in this example.  Simulation suggests to me that the probability of reaching $k=4$ or higher is just under $76\%$ while of reaching $k=5$ is about $25\%$

Comment: Good example, Henry. I just wonder if there is a formula for variable n, m, and p.

Comment: @Henry ok I see thanks for illustrating. By generating a sequence from n iid then sampling each sequence of length m, I'm not sure how m is distributed. It seems reasonable to distribute over different n, m and k and plot the empirical distributions.

Comment: See book scan statistics by Glaz,Naus, Wallenstine Chapter 4

Answer (score 0):

I can't afford the book Scan Statistics recommended by @Joenaus so this might be a partial or full duplicate as to what is in that book.

If $n$ is relatively small (say $n \leq 20$) and $n$ is an integer multiple of $m$, then the distribution of the maximum threshold being $k$ can be found with computer algebra systems such as *Mathematica*:

```
m = 5;
n = 20;
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   Max[Table[Sum[x[i], {i, j, j + m - 1}], {j, 1, n - m + 1}]],
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p], {i, 1, n}]];
TableForm[Table[{k, PDF[dist, k]}, {k, 0, m}],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"k", "Pr(Max(threshold) = k)"}}]
```

[image: Table of probabilities for the maximum observed threshold]

For $k=5$ we have for $p=1/2$:

```
-p^5*(-16+15*p+ 55*p^5- 100*p^6 + 45*p^7 - 20*p^10 + 50*p^11 - 40*p^12 + 10*p^13) /. p -> 1/2 // N
(* 0.24987 *)
```

which matches @Henry 's simulation result.