# Calculating expected trials before "X out of the previous Y" trials reach a threshold?

Tags: probability, distributions

Sorry; not a statistician; I don't know how to correctly word this. This came up with X (formerly Twitter)'s Community Notes system. If at any time 3 out of 5 of your previous community notes are rated unhelpful, you will be removed from the community notes program. Say there's a probability $p$ of any given note being rated unhelpful. Even if $p$ is quite low (eg 5%), on a long enough time frame, all contributors to the program are doomed to get kicked off. I want to know how one would calculate the statistical timeline for when that would happen with some likelihood.

Put more abstractly, say there's a bucket of infinitely many blue balls and red balls. You select balls at random with a probability $p$ of selecting a blue ball. Once you have reached a state where $X$ out of the previous $Y$ selections are blue balls, you stop. How many balls are you expected to select before you have a T% chance of reaching that state (where T could be some number like 50%).

=========

EDIT: That was probably unclear. It's not if your ratio is less than 3/5 (well, probably it is on Twitter -- I don't actually use community notes -- but for the sake of this question pretend it works the way I specified above). It's on a continuous sequence looking back at *only your last five draws*. So if you drew 5000 red balls, then encounter a sequence of blue-red-blue-red-blue, now 3 of your last 5 are blue. At which point you stop drawing, regardless of your 5000 red balls you drew earlier. The question is how many draws you can expect to make before any such combination is reached.

Some experimental results from a simulation:

```
 | X/Y | p     | mean      | median | max    | 
 |-------------------------------------------| 
 | 3/5 | 0.025 | 11549.359 | 8156   | 103632 | 
 | 3/5 | 0.05  | 1581.219  | 1075   | 16825  | 
 | 3/5 | 0.1   | 242.005   | 170    | 2076   | 
 | 3/5 | 0.15  | 85.589    | 61     | 770    | 
 | 3/5 | 0.2   | 44.398    | 32     | 332    | 
 | 3/5 | 0.25  | 27.136    | 20     | 204    | 
 | 3/5 | 0.5   | 7.181     | 5      | 43     |
```

Comment: I didn't address this in my answer below, but 'all contributors are doomed to get kicked off' is only true if you remove them after a *fixed* number of unhelpful posts and everyone has a non-zero chance for their posts to get rated as unhelpful (the latter is probably true). That is not how I would set up a moderation system, I'm sure you can intuitively understand that 10 bad posts are not the same if they're out of 11 or out of 11,000 total. More likely you'd try to understand each poster' s $p$. If you do want to condition on a fixed number of bad posts negative binomial will be the way.

Comment: @PBulls  It's not if your ratio is less than 3/5 (well, maybe it is -- I don't actually use community notes -- but for the sake of this question pretend it works the way I specified above). It's on a continuous sequence looking back at only your last five notes. So if you have 5000 helpful notes, then one night you post 5 notes with a sequence of unhelpful-helpful-unhelpful-helpful-unhelpful, now 3 of your last 5 are unhelpful. At which point you will be kicked off, regardless of your prior 5000 helpful ones.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I was answering a different question apparently, I'll leave the original here because the theory remains somewhat relevant.

To start with a bit of entry-level jargon: an outcome that can take a binary outcome (true/false, yes/no, helpful/unhelpful, ..) with probability $p$ is called a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) variable, and repeating $n$ independent Bernoulli experiments with common $p$ is described through the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) (of which Bernoulli is a special case).

The binomial distribution will allow you to calculate, for a *fixed* number of total draws $n$, what the probability is of seeing any number of blue balls $x$. There is a closely related negative binomial distribution that allows you to calculate the probability of having to make any number of $n$ draws before you see a *fixed* number of $x$ blue balls.

It sounds like you want to use the ratio $\frac{x}{n}$ rather than fixing either $x$ or $n$ however, and there a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) might be useful. Briefly, $B(\alpha, \beta)$ can express the probability mass of this ratio for $\alpha=x$ 'successes' (let's assume these are *un*helpful posts) and $\beta=n-x$ 'failures'. There's one caveat that you need both $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$, so for conditions that didn't occur yet you could use a small positive value like $0.001$.

One point I want to make here is that you usually wouldn't start looking at this ratio immediately, it's not because someone makes their first post a bad one that they should instantly be removed from the system, right? The same is true for the other designs but I hope you wouldn't look for just a single $n$ or unhelpful post $x$ either.

You can calculate all of these quantities through various statistical softwares and calculators, I can give some examples in R, assuming $p=0.05$:

- what is the probability of seeing at least 4 unhelpful posts out of the first 20? `pbinom(x = 3, size = 20, p = 0.05, lower.tail = FALSE)` $\approx 0.0159$, under our assumption that 5% of posts are unhelpful on average this person is not doing great.
- what is the probability of someone making 10 posts or less before seeing a first unhelpful one? `pnbinom(x = 10, size = 1, p = 0.05)` $\approx 0.432$, not unlikely but worse than average.
- someone has made 14 posts, 3 of which are bad. What is the probability that their value for $p$ is $\le 0.05$? `pbeta(0.05, 3, 11)` $\approx 0.0245$, not that much evidence that this person makes as many helpful posts as we assumed.

### Update

Apparently you are looking for only the last $n$ (5 in the question) draws out of which a specified $x$ (3) are unhelpful, sort of like a running average of Bernoulli experiments. To my knowledge this has no known distribution (see also for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502580/distribution-of-moving-average-of-bernoulli-distributed-variables)), but Monte Carlo sampling is definitely a valid way of getting some empirical probabilities here.

I considered calculating the probability for each given $p$ to produce (at least?) 3 out of 5 unhelpful posts, which itself is a binomial experiment you can do with the above formulae. You could then use the negative binomial (or geometric) distribution to predict the number of 5-posts until failure given that previous probability, but this does not take into account the moving window which introduces all sorts of edge cases and I can't really get it to match the expectations from the simulation results.

Comment: How does this apply to the case of the "continuous sequence", though? That is, you keep drawing balls until 3 out of the last 5 are blue -- but these are a moving window of draws. So once you draw ball #6, you toss back in ball #1, when you draw ball #7, you toss back in ball #7, etc. At some point, you will end up with a hand containing at least 3 blue balls.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, I misunderstood the question. I updated my response though couldn't add much actual information for this case.